# using java annotations in rythm template engine

Tags: rythm

In the quest of getting JUnit tests to be part of how we use Ryhtm we came up with the code snippet below. All went well until we added

```
@Test
```

which obviously is a java annotation and uses the @ marker as a syntax element that is also being used by Rythm. How can the desired effect be achieved to get the @annotation? To simply escape the @@ does not work it gives a

```
Syntax error on token "@", delete this token
```

error. **So How can a Java @ annotation be used** ?

I have also filed this as a bug report at https://github.com/greenlaw110/Rythm/issues/285

```java
@// This is a rythm template
@import static org.junit.Assert.*
@import org.junit.Test.*
@def static {
  class TestMe {
    String name;
    @Test
    public void testMe() {
      name="test";
      assertEquals("test",name);
    }
  }
}
@{
  TestMe testme=new TestMe();
  testme.name="testme";
}
The TestMe has the name @(testme.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a fully qualifying annotation it should work:

```
 @org.junit.Test
```

Answer (score 1):

`@import org.junit.Test.*` in your template code should be `@import org.junit.Test`, note that `.*` needs to be take off